# Automatic Dataset in BigQuery?

Tags: python, mysql, google-bigquery

I'm working in BigQuery with the DataSets from GA and I create some new tables for frequent analysis, and I have one question:
**It's posible to create an automatic upgrade from the data at this tables?**

The data from the tables comes from some queries about the GA Datasets, I need this to make a daily export from this data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently supported in BigQuery (although you could write your own scripts to do this on a periodic basis).

Scheduled queries are planned for a future version of the product. See:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38173739

Comment: isn't this corp link?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Got burnt by automatic redirect. I've fixed it to use the externally available name.